# Rewriting Matlab eig(A,B) (Generalized eigenvalues/eigenvectors) to C/C++

Tags: c++, matlab, linear-algebra, eigen, intel-mkl

Do anyone have any idea how can I rewrite `eig(A,B)` from Matlab used to calculate generalized eigenvector/eigenvalues? I've been struggling with this problem lately. So far:

Matlab definition of `eig` function I need:

```
[V,D] = eig(A,B) produces a diagonal matrix D of generalized
eigenvalues and a full matrix V whose columns are the corresponding
eigenvectors so that A*V = B*V*D.
```

1. So far I tried the `Eigen` library (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver.html)

My implementation looks like this:

```
std::pair<Matrix4cd, Vector4d> eig(const Matrix4cd& A, const Matrix4cd& B)
{
    Eigen::GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix4cd> solver(A, B);

    Matrix4cd V = solver.eigenvectors();
    Vector4d D = solver.eigenvalues();

    return std::make_pair(V, D);
}
```

But first thing that comes to my mind is, that I can't use `Vector4cd` as `.eigenvalues()` doesn't return complex values where Matlab does. Furthermore results of `.eigenvectors()` and `.eigenvalues()` for the same matrices are not the same at all:

C++:

```
Matrix4cd x;
Matrix4cd y;
pair<Matrix4cd, Vector4d> result;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        x.real()(i,j) = (double)(i+j+1+i*3);
        y.real()(i,j) = (double)(17 - (i+j+1+i*3));

        x.imag()(i,j) = (double)(i+j+1+i*3);
        y.imag()(i,j) = (double)(17 - (i+j+1+i*3));
    }
}
result = eig(x,y);
cout << result.first << endl << endl;
cout << result.second << endl << endl;
```

Matlab:

```
for i=1:1:4
    for j=1:1:4
        x(i,j) = complex((i-1)+(j-1)+1+((i-1)*3), (i-1)+(j-1)+1+((i-1)*3));
        y(i,j) = complex(17 - ((i-1)+(j-1)+1+((i-1)*3)), 17 - ((i-1)+(j-1)+1+((i-1)*3)));
    end
end

[A,B] = eig(x,y)
```

So I give `eig` the same 4x4 matrices holding values 1-16 ascending (x) and descending (y). But I receive different results, furthermore `Eigen` method returns double from eigenvalues while Matlab returns complex dobule. I also find out that there is other `Eigen` solver named `GeneralizedEigenSolver`. That one in the documentation (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1GeneralizedEigenSolver.html) has written that it solves `A*V = B*V*D` but to be honest I tried it and results (matrix sizes) are not the same size as Matlab so I got quite lost how it works (examplary results are on the website I've linked). It also has only .eigenvector method.

C++ results:

```
(-0.222268,-0.0108754) (0.0803437,-0.0254809) (0.0383264,-0.0233819) (0.0995482,0.00682079)
(-0.009275,-0.0182668) (-0.0395551,-0.0582127) (0.0550395,0.03434) (-0.034419,-0.0287563)
(-0.112716,-0.0621061) (-0.010788,0.10297) (-0.0820552,0.0294896) (-0.114596,-0.146384)
(0.28873,0.257988) (0.0166259,-0.0529934) (0.0351645,-0.0322988) (0.405394,0.424698)

-1.66983
-0.0733194
0.0386832
3.97933
```

Matlab results:

```
[A,B] = eig(x,y)


A =

  Columns 1 through 3

  -0.9100 + 0.0900i  -0.5506 + 0.4494i   0.3614 + 0.3531i
   0.7123 + 0.0734i   0.4928 - 0.2586i  -0.5663 - 0.4337i
   0.0899 - 0.4170i  -0.1210 - 0.3087i   0.0484 - 0.1918i
   0.1077 + 0.2535i   0.1787 + 0.1179i   0.1565 + 0.2724i

  Column 4

  -0.3237 - 0.3868i
   0.2338 + 0.7662i
   0.5036 - 0.3720i
  -0.4136 - 0.0074i


B =

  Columns 1 through 3

  -1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -1.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -4.5745 - 1.8929i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i

  Column 4

   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i
  -0.3317 + 1.1948i
```

2. Second try was with Intel IPP but it seems that it solves only `A*V = V*D` and support told me that it's not supported anymore.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/505270 (list of constructors for Intel IPP)

3. I got suggestion to move from Intel IPP to MKL. I did it and hit the wall again. I tried to check all algorithms for `Eigen` but it seems that there are only `A*V = V*D` problems solved. I was checking `lapack95.lib`. The list of algorithms used by this library is available there: 
   https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/index.htm#dsyev.htm

Somewhere on the web I could find topic on Mathworks when someone said that managed to solve my problem partially with usage of MKL:

http://jp.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/40050-generalized-eigenvalue-and-eigenvectors-differences-between-matlab-eig-a-b-and-mkl-lapack-dsygv

Person said that he/she used `dsygv` algorithm but I can't locate anything like that on the web. Maybe it's a typo.

Anyone has any other proposition/idea how can I implement it? Or maybe point my mistake. I'd appreciate that.

---

EDIT:
In comments I've received a hint that I was using `Eigen` solver wrong. My `A` matrix wasn't self-adjoint and my `B` matrix wasn't positive-definite. I took matrices from program I want to rewrite to C++ (from random iteration) and checked if they meet the requirements. They did:

```
Rj =

  1.0e+02 *

 Columns 1 through 3

   0.1302 + 0.0000i  -0.0153 + 0.0724i   0.0011 - 0.0042i
  -0.0153 - 0.0724i   1.2041 + 0.0000i  -0.0524 + 0.0377i
   0.0011 + 0.0042i  -0.0524 - 0.0377i   0.0477 + 0.0000i
  -0.0080 - 0.0108i   0.0929 - 0.0115i  -0.0055 + 0.0021i

  Column 4

  -0.0080 + 0.0108i
   0.0929 + 0.0115i
  -0.0055 - 0.0021i
   0.0317 + 0.0000i

Rt =

  Columns 1 through 3

   4.8156 + 0.0000i  -0.3397 + 1.3502i  -0.2143 - 0.3593i
  -0.3397 - 1.3502i   7.3635 + 0.0000i  -0.5539 - 0.5176i
  -0.2143 + 0.3593i  -0.5539 + 0.5176i   1.7801 + 0.0000i
   0.5241 + 0.9105i   0.9514 + 0.6572i  -0.7302 + 0.3161i

  Column 4

   0.5241 - 0.9105i
   0.9514 - 0.6572i
  -0.7302 - 0.3161i
   9.6022 + 0.0000i
```

As for `Rj` which is now my `A` - it is self-adjoint because `Rj = Rj'` and `Rj = ctranspose(Rj)`. (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AdjointMatrix.html)

As for `Rt` which is now my `B` - it is Positive-Definite what is checked with method linked to me. (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101132-how-do-i-determine-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite-using-matlab). So

```
>> [~,p] = chol(Rt)

p =

     0
```

I've rewritten matrices manually to C++ and performed `eig(A,B)` again with matrices meeting requirements:

```
Matrix4cd x;
Matrix4cd y;
pair<Matrix4cd, Vector4d> result;

x.real()(0,0) = 13.0163601949795;
x.real()(0,1) = -1.53172561296005;
x.real()(0,2) = 0.109594869350436;
x.real()(0,3) = -0.804231869422614;

x.real()(1,0) = -1.53172561296005;
x.real()(1,1) = 120.406645675346;
x.real()(1,2) = -5.23758765476463;
x.real()(1,3) = 9.28686785230169;

x.real()(2,0) = 0.109594869350436; 
x.real()(2,1) = -5.23758765476463;
x.real()(2,2) = 4.76648319080400;
x.real()(2,3) = -0.552823839520508;

x.real()(3,0) = -0.804231869422614;
x.real()(3,1) = 9.28686785230169;
x.real()(3,2) = -0.552823839520508;
x.real()(3,3) = 3.16510496622613;

x.imag()(0,0) = -0.00000000000000;
x.imag()(0,1) = 7.23946944213164;
x.imag()(0,2) = 0.419181335323979;
x.imag()(0,3) = 1.08441894337449;

x.imag()(1,0) = -7.23946944213164;
x.imag()(1,1) = -0.00000000000000;
x.imag()(1,2) = 3.76849276970080;
x.imag()(1,3) = 1.14635625342266;

x.imag()(2,0) = 0.419181335323979;
x.imag()(2,1) = -3.76849276970080;
x.imag()(2,2) = -0.00000000000000;
x.imag()(2,3) = 0.205129702522089;

x.imag()(3,0) = -1.08441894337449;
x.imag()(3,1) = -1.14635625342266;
x.imag()(3,2) = 0.205129702522089;
x.imag()(3,3) = -0.00000000000000;

y.real()(0,0) = 4.81562784930907;
y.real()(0,1) = -0.339731222392148;
y.real()(0,2) = -0.214319720979258;
y.real()(0,3) = 0.524107127885349;

y.real()(1,0) = -0.339731222392148;
y.real()(1,1) = 7.36354235698375;
y.real()(1,2) = -0.553927983436786;
y.real()(1,3) = 0.951404408649307;

y.real()(2,0) = -0.214319720979258;
y.real()(2,1) = -0.553927983436786;
y.real()(2,2) = 1.78008768533745;
y.real()(2,3) = -0.730246631850385;

y.real()(3,0) = 0.524107127885349;
y.real()(3,1) = 0.951404408649307;
y.real()(3,2) = -0.730246631850385;
y.real()(3,3) = 9.60215057284395;

y.imag()(0,0) = -0.00000000000000;
y.imag()(0,1) = 1.35016928394966;
y.imag()(0,2) = -0.359262708214312;
y.imag()(0,3) = -0.910512495060186;

y.imag()(1,0) = -1.35016928394966;
y.imag()(1,1) = -0.00000000000000;
y.imag()(1,2) = -0.517616473138836;
y.imag()(1,3) = -0.657235460367660;

y.imag()(2,0) = 0.359262708214312;
y.imag()(2,1) = 0.517616473138836;
y.imag()(2,2) = -0.00000000000000;
y.imag()(2,3) = -0.316090662865005;

y.imag()(3,0) = 0.910512495060186;
y.imag()(3,1) = 0.657235460367660;
y.imag()(3,2) = 0.316090662865005;
y.imag()(3,3) = -0.00000000000000;

result = eig(x,y);

cout << result.first << endl << endl;
cout << result.second << endl << endl;
```

And the results of C++:

```
(0.0295948,0.00562174) (-0.253532,0.0138373) (-0.395087,-0.0139696) (-0.0918132,-0.0788735)
(-0.00994614,-0.0213973) (-0.0118322,-0.0445976) (0.00993512,0.0127006) (0.0590018,-0.387949)
(0.0139485,-0.00832193) (0.363694,-0.446652) (-0.319168,0.376483) (-0.234447,-0.0859585)
(0.173697,0.268015) (0.0279387,-0.0103741) (0.0273701,0.0937148)  (-0.055169,0.0295393)

0.244233
2.24309
3.24152
18.664
```

Results of MATLAB:

```
>>  [A,B] = eig(Rj,Rt)

A =

  Columns 1 through 3

   0.0208 - 0.0218i   0.2425 + 0.0753i  -0.1242 + 0.3753i
  -0.0234 - 0.0033i  -0.0044 + 0.0459i   0.0150 - 0.0060i
   0.0006 - 0.0162i  -0.4964 + 0.2921i   0.2719 + 0.4119i
   0.3194 + 0.0000i  -0.0298 + 0.0000i   0.0976 + 0.0000i

  Column 4

  -0.0437 - 0.1129i
   0.2351 - 0.3142i
  -0.1661 - 0.1864i
  -0.0626 + 0.0000i

B =

   0.2442         0         0         0
        0    2.2431         0         0
        0         0    3.2415         0
        0         0         0   18.6640
```

`Eigenvalues` are the same! Nice, but why `Eigenvectors` are not similar at all?

Comment: Trying libraries at random isn't productive. Eigen is a comprehensive and beautifully designed library, with excellent docs. Are you sure it is not suitable?

Comment: Hello, I've spent ~10 hours on Eigen already. Looking at their documentation http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Eigenvalues__Module.html I can see that there are a few Eigen solvers and only two of them are used for generalized case. I've implemented both of them and inserted the same matrices as I do in Matlab. In both cases results were different + I had problem with structure and type of output data. I read whole documentation. Usually I try to find a clue, then I follow it till I am out of ideas and then try something different. It's better than sitting without idea what to do next.

Comment: A few notes: your `y` matrix is not positive definite as required by [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver.html) ("This class solves the generalized eigenvalue problem $ Av = \lambda Bv $. In this case, the matrix $ A $ should be selfadjoint and the matrix $ B $ should be positive definite."). See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101132-how-do-i-determine-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite-using-matlab) for determining if the matrix is PD. Likewise, `x` is not selfadjoint, but I'm out of room for this comment.

Comment: I've looked into Positive-definite and self-adjoint conditions. I was performing tests on matrices not suited for it. I've updated info from my new tests and eigenvaluesare working. I don't get why eigenvectors don't give the same results then. Must be some algorithm difference then, no?

Comment: why don't you try something simpler like SVD and debug your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem here with Eigen.

In fact for the second example run, Matlab and Eigen produced the very same result. Please remember from basic linear algebra that eigenvector are determined up to an arbitrary scaling factor. (I.e. if v is an eigenvector the same holds for alpha*v, where alpha is a non zero complex scalar.)

It is quite common that different linear algebra libraries compute different eigenvectors, but this does not mean that one of the two codes is wrong: it simply means that they choose a different scaling of the eigenvectors.

EDIT

The main problem with exactly replicating the scaling chosen by matlab is that `eig(A,B)` is a *driver* routine, which depending from the different properties of `A` and `B` may call different libraries/routines, and apply extra steps like balancing the matrices and so on. By quickly inspecting your example, I would say that in this case matlab is enforcing following condition:

- `all(imag(V(end,:))==0)` (the last component of each eigenvector is real)

but not imposing other constraints. This unfortunately means that the scaling is not unique, and probably depends on intermediate results of the generalised eigenvector algorithm used. In this case I'm not able to give you advice on how to *exactly* replicate matlab: knowledge of the internal working of matlab is required.

As a general remark, in linear algebra usually one does not care too much about eigenvector scaling, since this is usually completely irrelevant for the problem solved, when the eigenvectors are just used as intermediate results.

The only case in which the scaling has to be defined exactly, is when you are going to give a graphic representation of the eigenvalues.

Comment: As a note: this is a recurring issue, please cfr. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17682626/1499402

Comment: Thanks for a helpful answer. Is there any way to match the scaling used by Matlab with one of my library resutls. Lets say Eigen?

Comment: Please see edit above for an answer to this further question.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvector scaling in Matlab seems to be based on normalizing them to 1.0 (ie. the absolute value of the biggest term in each vector is 1.0). In the application I was using it also returns the left eigenvector rather than the more commonly used right eigenvector. This could explain the differences between Matlab and the eigensolvers in Lapack MKL.